# Cannot merge node because of null property value (Neo4j - PUBG dataset)

Tags: neo4j, cypher, pubg

i'm expanding my horizon and currently fiddling around in Neo4j.
Followed a few courses on Udemy and I thought I would master it enough to load a custom dataset :)

I want to load a PlayerUnknown's Battlegrounds dataset.
Source: https://www.kaggle.com/skihikingkevin/pubg-match-deaths
Dataset: kill_match_stats_final_0.csv

To make the data readable:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///kill_match_stats_final_0.csv' AS row
WITH row.killed_by AS MurderWeapon, row.killer_name AS Murderer, toInteger(row.killer_placement) AS RankMurderer, 
     row.killer_position_x AS MurderPositionX, row.killer_position_y AS MurderPositionY, 
     row.map AS Map, row.match_id AS MatchID, toInteger(row.time) AS TimeOfDeathSec, 
     row.victim_name AS Victim, toInteger(row.victim_placement) AS RankVictim,
     row.victim_position_x AS VictimPositionX, row.victim_position_y AS VictimPositionY
RETURN MurderWeapon, Murderer, RankMurderer, MurderPositionX, MurderPositionY, Map, MatchID, TimeOfDeathSec, Victim, RankVictim, VictimPositionX, VictimPositionY
LIMIT 5;
```

My idea was to create 2 nodes: Murderer and Victim with the label Player
The edge will be kills:
[Node-edge-schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QTLT.png)

When I want to load the dataset I get an error, *Cannot merge the following node because of null property value for 'name': (:Player {name: null})*

At first I thought the in place integer conversion was the problem. So I removed those but that didn't solve the problem.
This statement I'm trying to run:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///kill_match_stats_final_0.csv' AS row
WITH row
MERGE (Murderer:Player{name:row.killer_name, rank:row.killer_placement})
MERGE (Victim:Player{name:row.victim_name, rank:row.victim_placement})
MERGE (Murderer)-[killed:Killed{
                                        `Killed With`:row.killed_by,    
                                        `KillerX`:row.killer_position_x, 
                                        `KillerY`:row.killer_position_y, 
                                        `Map`:row.map, 
                                        `MatchID`:row.match_id, 
                                        `Time of Death`:row.time, 
                                        `VictimX`:row.victim_position_x, 
                                        `VictimY`:row.victim_position_y
}]->(Victim)
;
```

I have the feeling it is staring right in my face but I can't see it :P

**Question** What is wrong with my statement to load the csv file?

Instead of downloading the large files, you can download a short version here: https://storage.stijvehark.nl/s/OmdSL2oljVIyG2hx

## Update 1

After the comment of @Graphileon
I had a new look into the data. I assumed (yeah I know....) that all columns would contain data. I used his script and it runs good. So I tried this one:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///kill_match_stats_smalll_batch.csv' AS row
WITH row
RETURN row
```

That also looks good. Examening the results from the dataset I found this:

```
{
  "killer_name": null,
  "victim_position_y": "0.0",
  "victim_position_x": "0.0",
  "killer_position_x": null,
  "victim_placement": "26.0",
  "killer_position_y": null,
  "match_id": "2U4GBNA0YmnLSqvEycnTjo-KT000vfUnhSA2vfVhVPe1QBwCTNTBJ5B_1Ocel6nY",
  "victim_name": "xuezhiqian717",
  "killed_by": "Bluezone",
  "killer_placement": null,
  "time": "879",
  "map": "MIRAMAR"
}
```

I was already curious about how the data would be presented when you kill yourself, fall or kill yourself with a grenade for example. I will have a look into that later on. Your suggestion I like your suggestion about the player. I will try to use that instead.

## Update 2

Some head breaking but I managed to import all the players with the following:

```
// Add constraint
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (p:Player) ASSERT p.name IS UNIQUE

// Create nodes:
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///kill_match_stats_smalll_batch.csv' AS row
WITH row
MERGE (:Player{name:
                    CASE WHEN row.killer_name IS NOT NULL 
                        THEN row.killer_name
                        ELSE 'System-' + row.killed_by END
            })
MERGE (:Player{name:
                CASE WHEN row.victim_name IS NOT NULL 
                    THEN row.victim_name
                    ELSE 'System-' + row.killed_by END
                })
```

This imported all the players, for players that are killed due the bluezone or did fall to their death I added a user 'System-'

Now for creating the edges:

```
 // Create edges:
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///kill_match_stats_smalll_batch.csv' AS row
WITH row
MERGE (Player)-[killed:Killed{
                                        `Killed With`:row.killed_by,    
                                        `KillerX`:
                                            CASE WHEN row.killer_position_x IS NOT NULL 
                                            THEN row.killer_position_x
                                            ELSE '0' END, 
                                        `KillerY`:
                                            CASE WHEN row.killer_position_y IS NOT NULL 
                                            THEN row.killer_position_y
                                            ELSE '0' END, 
                                        `Map`:row.map, 
                                        `MatchID`:row.match_id, 
                                        `Time of Death`:row.time, 
                                        `VictimX`:
                                            CASE WHEN row.victim_position_x IS NOT NULL 
                                            THEN row.victim_position_x
                                            ELSE '0' END,
                                        `VictimY`:
                                            CASE WHEN row.victim_position_y IS NOT NULL 
                                            THEN row.victim_position_y
                                            ELSE '0' END
}]->(Player)
```

That didn't goes as planned :P

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiGts.png)

Next thing to figure that one out, any guidance on how to tackle this?

Comment: Your MERGE (Player)-[:Killed)->(Player) obviously fails. You have to get the nodes first. BTW, if our answers are useful, please acknowledge by upvoting / accepting

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

When `MERGE` is hitting a *null* value, it means that you have rows with an empty value in your *killer_name* and/or *victim_name* fields.
One  way to find these rows:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///kill_match_stats_final_0.csv' AS row
WITH row
WHERE TRIM(COALESCE(row.killer_name,'')) = '' 
      OR 
      TRIM(COALESCE(row.victim_name,'')) = ''
RETURN row
```

In addition about the model that you have chosen. If a player that has killed someone can later be the victim, I would consider using just :Player nodes and set a unique CONSTRAINT on Player.name. Who is the killer and who is victim can be derived from the direction of the relationship. If you label the nodes as :Murderer and :Victim will force you to create two nodes in case a Murderer becomes a Victim at some point in time, and you will have two players with the same name

Comment: Thank you for your response.

I couldn't clarify why the killer_name would return an empty value. The CSV contains in every column a value, so it must return something. Your code helped me to have a new look into :)

Comment: you also have to check victim_name, because you MERGE against :Player nodes